# ExtJS reloading store on button click event with different parameter

Tags: servlets, extjs4

I am new to ExtJs and I am using ExtJs4.

Now As shown in below image, There is one textfield named keywords, What I want to do is When I click on the button it will pass data of `textfield` to servlet and display resulted record in `grid`.

[image]

Now I have no idea how to do this. I am receiving JSON data response from servlet but don't know how to reload the store and refresh the grid.

> Below is code for my store and grid.

```
Ext.define("Post", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/ezdi/searchServlet',
        method: 'POST',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows'
            //,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    },

    fields: [{
        name: 'docid',
        mapping: 'docid'
    }, {
        name: 'mrn',
        mapping: 'mrn'
    }, {
        name: 'fname',
        mapping: 'fname'
    }]
});

var gridDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Post'
});

// Data store for grid end

Ext.define('Ezdi.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
    alias: 'widget.ezdigrid',
    initComponent: function() {
        var config = {
            store: gridDataStore,
            columns: [{
                header: "DocID",
                width: 100,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'docid'
            }, {
                header: "MRN",
                width: 100,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'mrn'
            }, {
                header: "FirstName",
                width: 100,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'fname'
            }],
            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: false,
                autoLoad: false
            },
            loadMask: true
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Search',
    handler: function() {
        store.clearFilter(); //clear previous search value
        var searchValue = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId").getValue(); //get new value 
        store.load().filter('jsonGridFielName', searchValue); //load filtered data
    }
}
```

And for for multiple `textfield` search:

```
//FILTERS
var searchValue1 = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId1").getValue(); //value1
var searchValue2 = Ext.getCmp("textFieldId2").getValue(); //value2
var noValue = "0000xxxx"; //no Value, for empty field, use value that you are sure it is not going to be searched!!!
var clear = store.clearFilter(); //shortcut

if (!searchValue1 && !searchValue2) {
    clear;
    store.load().filter("jsonGridFielName1", noValue);
} else if (searchValue1) {
    clear;
    store.load().filter('jsonGridFielName1', searchValue1);
    //...else if(searchValue n...)...
} else {
    clear;
    store.load().filter('jsonGridFielName2', searchValue2);
}
```

Comment: its fine but now problem is I want to put filter for individual field based on user requirement.In my example my fields are(keywords,mrn,docid,fname). I want to put filter on each this field and I will add textfield for them in my html.. so please suggest me that as well..

Comment: hey ! I guess the 'jsonGridFieldName1' and 'jsonGridFieldName2' will be parameter name, which I try to get it in servlets. Also I dont kn how I can create the store using these fields..... If u say so then I post my full code here, so that u can help me more..

Comment: jsonGridFieldName would be gridpanel columns dataIndex dataIndex:"name", or store field names, fields:[name:"name..." witch are alway the same, if not using mapping.

Comment: ok now I got it, but my filter field is not part of my grid, so how to do this, plzz chk the code in answer I posted.. its not working...  What I want to do is,, In click event of button the value in textfield should be passed to servlet which will then perform query and return result back to store and refresh the grid

Comment: yet i m looking to solve this problem... as I m trying hard for it not getting the solution.. so kindly suggest me something after looking to my answer

Answer (score 2):

## ezdigrid.js

---

```
// Data store for grid start
Ext.define("Post", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/ezdi/searchServlet',
        method: 'GET',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows'
            //,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    },

    fields: [{
        name: 'docid',
        mapping: 'docid'
    }, {
        name: 'mrn',
        mapping: 'mrn'
    }, {
        name: 'fname',
        mapping: 'fname'
    }]
});

var gridDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    // pageSize: 10,
    model: 'Post'
});

// Data store for grid end

Ext.define('Ezdi.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
    alias: 'widget.ezdigrid',
    initComponent: function() {
        var config = {
            store: gridDataStore,
            columns: [{
                //id:'ms',
                header: "DocID",
                width: 100,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'docid'
            }, {
                header: "MRN",
                width: 100,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'mrn'
            }, {
                header: "FirstName",
                width: 100,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'fname'
            }],
            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: false,
                autoLoad: false
            },
            loadMask: true
        }; // eo config object

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));


        // call parent
        Ezdi.Grid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);

        // load the store at the latest possible moment
        this.on({
            afterlayout: {
                scope: this,
                single: true,
                fn: function() {
                    this.store.load({
                        params: {
                            start: 0,
                            limit: 30
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    } // eo function initComponent

});
```

## demo.html

---

```
//handler for button click event
fbar: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Search',
    handler: function() {
        var value = Ext.getCmp('_keyword').getValue(); //_keyword is textField
        gridDataStore.load().filter('keywords', value);
    }
}]
```

## MyServlet

---

```
keyword = request.getParameter("keywords");

//code for quesry processing
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `extraParams` in your `model`.

```
extraParams: {
    keywords: 'your-value'
}
```

Put following code in your button click handler.

```
gridDataStore.proxy.extraParams.keywords = 'new value';
gridDataStore.load();
```